# Make terminator ask for permission before closing if something is being executed

Tags: gnome-terminal, terminator

I normally use Terminator as a terminal instead of the GNOME one. So far I am really happy with Terminator. However, the GNOME terminal asks for permission before closing if something is running in the terminal (for example if you ssh to another computer using GNOME terminal and you want to close that terminal by clicking the <kbd>X</kbd> button, it will prompt you with a message asking for permission to close) while Terminator doesn't. Is it possible to do this in Terminator?

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the terminatorlib container.py file usually located in `/usr/share/terminator/terminatorlib/container.py`
locate the contruct_confirm_close || remove it and paste this default

```
def construct_confirm_close(self, window, reqtype):
        """Create a confirmation dialog for closing things"""
        
        # skip this dialog if applicable
        if self.config['suppress_multiple_term_dialog']:
            return gtk.RESPONSE_ACCEPT
        
        dialog = gtk.Dialog(_('Close?'), window, gtk.DIALOG_MODAL)
        dialog.set_has_separator(False)
        dialog.set_resizable(False)
    
        dialog.add_button(gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, gtk.RESPONSE_REJECT)
        c_all = dialog.add_button(gtk.STOCK_CLOSE, gtk.RESPONSE_ACCEPT)
        c_all.get_children()[0].get_children()[0].get_children()[1].set_label(
                _('Close _Terminals'))
    
        primary = gtk.Label(_('<big><b>Close multiple terminals?</b></big>'))
        primary.set_use_markup(True)
        primary.set_alignment(0, 0.5)
        secondary = gtk.Label(_('This %s has several terminals open. Closing \
the %s will also close all terminals within it.') % (reqtype, reqtype))
        secondary.set_line_wrap(True)
                    
        labels = gtk.VBox()
        labels.pack_start(primary, False, False, 6)
        labels.pack_start(secondary, False, False, 6)
    
        image = gtk.image_new_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_DIALOG_WARNING,
                                         gtk.ICON_SIZE_DIALOG)
        image.set_alignment(0.5, 0)
    
        box = gtk.HBox()
        box.pack_start(image, False, False, 6)
        box.pack_start(labels, False, False, 6)
        dialog.vbox.pack_start(box, False, False, 12)

        checkbox = gtk.CheckButton(_("Do not show this message next time"))
        dialog.vbox.pack_end(checkbox)
    
        dialog.show_all()

        result = dialog.run()
        
        # set configuration
        self.config.base.reload()
        self.config['suppress_multiple_term_dialog'] = checkbox.get_active()
        self.config.save()

        dialog.destroy()
                
        return(result)
```

Please note in some cases or versions of terminator the '`GTK_OBJECT` may be referenced as `gtk` or `GTK`