# Make gnome terminal warn before closing even there is no process running?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, gnome-terminal

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and gnome-terminal 3.18.3.

I can't seem to find an option to get a warning before (accidentally) closing the terminal. It seems like that there used to be an option to change it in gconf-editor (apps -> Gnome-Terminal) but it is not there anymore.

I see a few similar but unanswered questions for other terminal on this as well (e.g. [Terminal not prompting before closing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775469/terminal-not-prompting-before-closing) and [Make terminator ask for permission before closing if something is being executed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/798188/make-terminator-ask-for-permission-before-closing-if-something-is-being-executed))

Comment: The two links shared are the same question

Comment: They don't share the same question, the first one regards to `LXTerminal` and asks for a prompt regardless of the state, the second one regards to `Terminator` and asks for a prompt in the state if a a foreground is running.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: gnome-terminal only prompts you if a foreground process is active and the configurable option `confirm-close` is true.

The long answer is:

As you can see in [source code](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-terminal/tree/src/terminal-window.c?h=gnome-3-18#n3654), gnome-terminal checks vor `TERMINAL_SETTING_CONFIRM_CLOSE_KEY` when it receives a window close request.

[Here you will see](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-terminal/tree/src/terminal-schemas.h?h=gnome-3-18#n66) that it maps to `confirm-close`.

You may get or set this setting using

```
gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings confirm-close
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings confirm-close true
```

The source of the function that decides if a confirmation is needed [is here](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-terminal/tree/src/terminal-window.c?h=gnome-3-18#n3635).

gnome-terminal only asks for a confirmation if confirm-close is true **and** if a foreground process is active in at least one tab. So if you want to always be asked before closing a gnome-terminal window you have create one tab and start a foreground process in it, i. e.

> ping -i 10 127.0.0.1

Furthermore you have to activate tabs:

> menu -> terminal -> settings -> open new terminal in: tabs

You may create a gnome-terminal profile which starts such a process automaticly. So you can configure gnome-terminal to start that profile on startup or you may easy start it yourself selecting

> file -> new terminal -> your profile

from the menu.

Comment: works for gnome-terminal version 3.26.2

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I wanted to have a profile that ran `nvim`. Since gnome-terminal wouldn't know if the buffer had unsaved changes, I wanted it to always prompt.

To that end, instead of making the profile command `nvim`, I made it `/bin/sh -i -c nvim`. The `-i`, making the shell interactive, makes gnome-terminal think that `nvim` is a foreground job that has yet to exit. Thus it will always prompt.

Perhaps you can use something like that.

Comment: Huge! I put `/bin/sh -i -c $SHELL` in my default profile and now all my terminals ask me for confirmation before I accidentally "x" out of them. Terrible design to not have a standard preference toggle for this at the entire desktop/window manager level, but this is good enough for a lot of needs!