# How do I remove the "X" button on the tabs in terminator?

Tags: customization, terminator, tabs

I really like terminator, but it has one big drawback: Sometimes when I try to switch to another tab, I accidentally hit the "X" button on the right of the tab. Then that tab closes, and I lose a lot of work.

Is there a way that I can remove the close button labeled "X"?

This question is related to the question "[Make terminator ask for permission before closing if something is being executed](https://askubuntu.com/q/798188)". I could live with the proposed solution there, but unfortunately it doesn't work for me as the suggested file doesn't exist in my install. I can't comment there since I don't have enough reputation points.

Thank you!

Comment: I fixed the location of the file in the linked answer.

Comment: But, I tried testing out that fix, and it doesn't work, plus it was copied from https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=171337 as the actual fix needs to be `Gtk.whatever` not `gtk.whatever`.  Anyways, I cannot see anyway to block or make those tabs confirm if being closed or not.